# How to craft CSS selector that depends on which html tag/textnode the targeted element contains

Tags: css

```
<td>Some text yada yada yada yada</td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td>Some more text yada yada yada yada</td>
```

with

```
td{white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis}
```

If the window is sized just right (at least in Chrome 92), ellipsis appear after the text box - even though the full text box is already shown, and there's no whitespace between it and the closing `</td>` tag.

I'd like to be able to specify CSS along the lines of

```
td:has(:textnode){overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis}
```

or

```
td:only(input){text-overflow:unset}
```

Neither of those work, but is there any current option that would do what I want, short of putting `id`/`class` on the `td` tags?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When defining styles, you're not able to specify which child nodes the current selector has, only the other way around, e.g. `td > input { .. }` would select only inputs which have a direct `td` parent.

1. It'd make a lot of sense to add classes like `<td class="wrap-text">`.
2. You could wrap the text into `<span>` elements and select those, like `td > span { text-overflow: ellipsis; }`